# how to save my position in listview and change image of my button when scroll

Tags: java, android

I have a list of music.In my row of listview I have play button.
when user click on play button , it starts to play my music and i change my background of my play button.
I want when user selected another position to play, the previous play button background change to unselected and the new one selected background.
another my problem is that when I scroll my list view , my background change to the first picture and it doesnt show which position is playing.I think when my listview update, I can not save my position.

here is my code(this my play button click),

```
 play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                if (rowView != lastview || mediaPlayer == null) {
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_selected);
                    play(position);
                    indexStore.setindex(position);
                    if (lastview != null)

                        lastview = rowView;
                } else {
                    indexStore.setindex(0);
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_unselected);
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                    //lastview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_white_matte);
                    lastview = null;
                }
            }
        });
```

and here is my whole class:

```
public class Main extends Activity {

    static Splash splash;
    public static AppList applist;
    static Noti_Queue noti_queue;
    public static Video_List video_list;
    AutoUpdatePushe autoUpdatePushe;
    ListView listView;
    Adaptor adaptor;
    private MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
    static View lastview = null;
    static MyIndexStore indexStore;
    public static Routpic routpic;
    static List<String> array_audio = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lines1 = new ArrayList<String>();
    List<String> lines2 = new ArrayList<String>();


    InputStream in;
    BufferedReader reader;
    String line = "1";
    String[] tracks;
    String[] names;
    String[] infos;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        indexStore = new MyIndexStore(getApplicationContext());

        setContentView(R.layout.main_activity);
        routpic = new Routpic(getApplicationContext());

        autoUpdatePushe = new AutoUpdatePushe(getApplicationContext());
        if (splash == null) {
            splash = new Splash(this);
            splash.set_identity("1");
        }


        if (applist == null) {
            applist = new AppList(this);
            applist.set_identity("1");
        }

        if (noti_queue == null) {
            noti_queue = new Noti_Queue(this);
            noti_queue.set_identity("1");
        }


        if (video_list == null) {
            video_list = new Video_List(this);
            video_list.set_identity("1");
        }
        Button video = (Button) findViewById(R.id.rate_btn);
        if (getResources().getString(R.string.showvideolist).equals("1")) {
            video.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            video.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }

        initiate();


        mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.a15);
        listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        ReadText1();
        names = lines1.toArray(new String[0]);// = {"track one","the seconnd track","a nice track","name name name","the seconnd track","a nice track","name name name"};
        ReadText2();
        infos = lines2.toArray(new String[0]);
        tracks = array_audio.toArray(new String[0]);
        adaptor = new Adaptor(getApplicationContext(), tracks, names, infos);
        listView.setAdapter(adaptor);
        mediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(new OnCompletionListener() {

            @Override
            public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer arg0) {
                if (lastview != null) {
                    ImageView play = (ImageView) lastview.findViewById(R.id.play_stop);
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_unselected);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private static void initiate() {
        XmlPullParserFactory pullParserFactory;
        try {
            pullParserFactory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();

            XmlPullParser parser = pullParserFactory.newPullParser();

            InputStream in_s = G.context.getAssets().open("temp.xml");
            parser.setFeature(XmlPullParser.FEATURE_PROCESS_NAMESPACES, false);
            parser.setInput(in_s, null);
            routpic.parseXML(parser);
        } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("EROR", "nabod");
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
            Log.i("EROR", "nabod");

        }
        array_audio.clear();
        for (int i = 0; i < routpic.names.size(); i++) {
            array_audio.add(routpic.names.get(i));
            Log.i("LOG2", "" + routpic.names.get(i));
        }


    }

    private void play(int index) {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        index++;
        String s = "mp3/a" + index + ".mp3";
        //Resources resources = getResources();

        AssetFileDescriptor afd;
        try {
            afd = getAssets().openFd(s);
            mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mediaPlayer.setDataSource(afd.getFileDescriptor(), afd.getStartOffset(), afd.getLength());
            mediaPlayer.prepare();
            mediaPlayer.start();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    //  final int resourceId = resources.getIdentifier(s , "raw", getPackageName());


    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mediaPlayer.release();
        listView.invalidateViews();
        super.onPause();
    }


    private void ReadText1() {
        lines1.clear();
        line = "1";
        try {
            in = this.getAssets().open("names.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            while (line != null) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (line != null)
                    lines1.add(line);
                else
                    break;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    private void ReadText2() {
        lines2.clear();
        line = "1";
        try {
            in = this.getAssets().open("infos.txt");
            reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            while (line != null) {
                line = reader.readLine();
                if (line != null)
                    lines2.add(line);
                else
                    break;
            }

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


    public class Adaptor extends ArrayAdapter<String> {

        private final Context context;
        private final String[] tracks;
        private final String[] names;
        private final String[] infos;
        Typeface type_face;

        public Adaptor(Context context, String[] tracks, String[] names, String[] infos) {
            super(context, R.layout.track, tracks);
            this.context = context;
            this.tracks = tracks;
            this.names = names;
            this.infos = infos;
            type_face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "ARLRDBD.TTF");
        }


        @Override
        public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            final View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.track, parent, false);
            // rowView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_white_matte);
            TextView name = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.track_name);
            name.setText(names[position]);
            name.setTypeface(type_face);
            //TextView info = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.track_info);
            //info.setText(infos[position]);
            name.setTypeface(type_face);
            AlphaAnimation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0.0f, 1.0f);
            rowView.setAnimation(fadeIn);
            fadeIn.setDuration(500 * (position % 4));

            ////
            final ImageView ringtone = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.ringtone);
            if (position == indexStore.getindex())
                ringtone.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_ringtone_seted);
            final ImageView play = (ImageView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.play_stop);
            ringtone.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    //ringtone.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_ringtone_selected);
                    setringtone(position, ringtone);
                    //mediaPlayer.release();
                    //rowView .setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_white_matte);
                    play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_unselected);


                }
            });

            play.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    if (rowView != lastview || mediaPlayer == null) {
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_selected);
                        play(position);
                        indexStore.setindex(position);
                        if (lastview != null)

                            lastview = rowView;
                    } else {
                        indexStore.setindex(0);
                        play.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_play_unselected);
                        mediaPlayer.release();
                        //lastview.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.btn_white_matte);
                        lastview = null;
                    }
                }
            });
            return rowView;
        }

        private void setringtone(final int position, final ImageView ringtone) {
            /*Intent intent = new Intent (context, Ringtone.class);
            intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            intent.putExtra("name", tracks[position]);
            context.startActivity(intent);*/
            //ringtone.setImageResource(R.drawable.n_btn_ringtone_unselected);
            final RelativeLayout dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.config);
            dialog.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            Button ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.ok_button);
            Button cancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
            Typeface type_face = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "ARLRDBD.TTF");
            ok.setTypeface(type_face);
            cancel.setTypeface(type_face);
            ok.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    indexStore.setindex(position);
                    set(tracks[position], 1, ringtone, position);
                }
            });
            cancel.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {
                    dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    mediaPlayer.release();
                }
            });
        }

    }


    public void set(String name, int type, ImageView ringtone, int position) {
        // mohammd
        //set ringtone
        //adaptor.setNotifyOnChange(true);
        listView.invalidateViews();
        Resources resources = getResources();

        //final int id = resources.getIdentifier(name , "raw", getPackageName());//name 5


        String ringtoneuri = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/media/ringtone";
        File file1 = new File(ringtoneuri);
        file1.mkdirs();

        File newSoundFile = new File(ringtoneuri, names[position] + ".mp3");//+ ".mp3"

        ContentResolver mCr = this.getContentResolver();
        try {
            byte[] readData = new byte[1024];

            InputStream fis = getAssets().open("mp3/a" + name + ".mp3");

            FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(newSoundFile);

            int i = fis.read(readData);

            while (i != -1) {
                fos.write(readData, 0, i);
                i = fis.read(readData);
            }

            fos.close();
        } catch (IOException io) {
        }

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DATA, newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.TITLE, names[position] + ".mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "audio/mp3");
        values.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.SIZE, newSoundFile.length());
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.ARTIST, R.string.app_name);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_RINGTONE, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_NOTIFICATION, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_ALARM, true);
        values.put(MediaStore.Audio.Media.IS_MUSIC, false);

        Uri uri = MediaStore.Audio.Media.getContentUriForPath(newSoundFile.getAbsolutePath());
        Uri newUri = mCr.insert(uri, values);
        try {
            Uri rUri = RingtoneManager.getValidRingtoneUri(this);
            RingtoneManager ringtoneManager = new RingtoneManager(getApplicationContext());
            if (rUri != null)
                ringtoneManager.setStopPreviousRingtone(true);
            switch (type) {
                case 1:
                    //ring tone
                    ringtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    //Notification
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION, newUri);
                    break;
                case 3:
                    //Alarm
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM, newUri);
                    break;

                default:
                    //ringtone
                    RingtoneManager.setActualDefaultRingtoneUri(getApplicationContext(), RingtoneManager.TYPE_RINGTONE, newUri);
                    break;
            }

        } catch (Throwable t) {
            Log.e("catch", "catch exception" + t.getMessage());
        }
        RelativeLayout dialog = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.config);
        dialog.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        mediaPlayer.release();

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.set_message), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




    public void more(View view) {
        applist.Display();
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        splash.Display();
        splash = null;
        super.onBackPressed();
    }



    public void video(View view) {
        video_list.Display();
    }


}
```

Comment: Add a variable in your adapter "selectedTrack" that you can reuse in getView

Comment: how to change it?

Comment: Change it with the new position in your onClickListener, then check the selected position in getView to set row background.

Comment: would you please say how to change new position ? a piece of code please

Comment: I'm sorry if this doesn't help answering your question, but it needs to be said : your code is half-crazy, you should have someone review it before trying to use it. I can't point out everything wrong with it, but please, don't use InputStream as a (package-scoped) class attribute without ever closing them.

Answer (score 0):

Use a boolean **Flag** to identify the button state example like : `isPlaying` and change the background like  `imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.wave);` a full working example is available here to get acquitted more.

[Audio Recorder](https://github.com/alkathirikhalid/android-uni-foundation/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/alkathirikhalid/audiorecorder/MainActivity.java)

Cheers.

Comment: I have just one button not two button

Comment: Correct the same concept can be applied to that one button state.